# Nested LINQ query selection

Tags: c#, linq

Please consider following example class construct:

```
public class Company
{
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public List<Subdivision> Subdivisions { get; set; }
}
public class Subdivision
{
    public string SubdivisionName { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
}
```

Example variable of a List:

```
List<Company> CompanyList = new List<Company>();
CompanyList.Add(new Company
    {
        CompanyName = "TestCompany",
        Subdivisions = new List<Subdivision>
        {
            { new Subdivision 
            {
               SubdivisionName = "TestSubdivision",
               Employees = new List<Employee>
                {
                    { new Employee
                        {
                            EmployeeID = 1,
                            EmployeeName = "John"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }}
        }
    });
```

**I want to get the EmployeeName just by EmployeeID.** Consider this code:

```
if (CompanyList.Any(x => x.Subdivisions.Any(y => y.Employees.Any(z => z.EmployeeID == 1))))
{
    int i1 = CompanyList.IndexOf(CompanyList.Where(x => x.Subdivisions.Any(y => y.Employees.Any(z => z.EmployeeID == 1))).Select(x => x).First());
    int i2 = CompanyList[i1].Subdivisions.IndexOf(CompanyList[i1].Subdivisions.Where(x => x.Employees.Any(z => z.EmployeeID == 1)).Select(x => x).First());
    int i3 = CompanyList[i1].Subdivisions[i2].Employees.IndexOf(CompanyList[i1].Subdivisions[i2].Employees.Where(z => z.EmployeeID == 1).Select(x => x).First());

    string i = CompanyList[i1].Subdivisions[i2].Employees[i3].EmployeeName;
    Console.WriteLine(i);                        
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee with ID 1 not found!");
}
```

This works just fine; however, it seems rather bloated up if I just want to retrieve a piece of data without getting the indexes. Is there any other approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.110).aspx) to search for all employees in all divisions in all companies and then use [FirstOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure null would be returned if no employee would be found

```
var employee = CompanyList.SelectMany(company => company.Subdivisions.SelectMany(division => division.Employees))
                          .FirstOrDefault(emp => emp.EmployeeID == 1);
if (employee != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(employee.EmployeeName); //prints John                  
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Employee with ID 1 not found!");
}
```